Is it allowed to write a vacuous truth using the present tense but not the past subjunctive?
My experience of learning English grammar is that I should use the subjunctive form when I write an unrealistic event (said by my teacher and several resources that I read long time ago).
The sentence is:

If Tokyo is in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia.

I took that sentence right from this intereseting topic about a vacuous truth. It's well-known that Tokyo IS in Japan, that means, writing Tokyo is in Spain is unrealistic, then why would the writer not write this way:

If tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Towers were in Bolivia.

Or are those just the same? That means the second suggestion of mine is allowed?
Please elaborate your answer as I want to deepen my knowledge about subjunctive.
Thank you very much in advance.

There's nothing wrong with your original sentence. But if you wanted to use the subjunctive, then the correct sentence would be "If Tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower would be in Bolivia."

This construction with the present tense in both clauses is sometimes used as a strong negation of the statement in the if-clause (which always starts the sentence). For example: "If that's genetics, then I'm the Queen of Sheba" https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/headlines/2013/jan/if-thats-genetics-then-im-queen-sheba and "If that’s a Caesar salad, then I’m the emperor of Rome."

Quite independently of your question, I think you are confusing the words "unreal" and "unrealistic".

Yes, I'd like to see a source for the rule "I should use the subjunctive form when I write an unrealistic event", because that doesn't seem a usual English rule, although it may apply in certain cases.

were/would be, not were/were


If tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Towers were in Bolivia.

Why the first use of "were" is correct and the second is not, is strictly a matter of usage (a usage that came into being for a reason that could be simple or mysterious, but which does not concern grammar, although it would be nice to mention that reason in a grammar if it were possible (in a few words)). The grammatical fact to contend with is that  the were-subjunctive (expressing hypothesis) is found in clauses introduced by certain conjunctions or in nominal clauses introduced by such verbs as "wish", and that "would" does the same thing  in main clauses, but not in subordinate clauses.

(CoGEL § 3.62) The were-subjunctive
The were-subjunctive (or past subjunctive) is hypothetical or unreal in meaning, being used in adverbial clauses introduced by such conjunctions as if, as if, as though, though, and in nominal clauses after verbs like wish and
suppose […]. This subjunctive is limited to the one form were, and thus breaks the concord rule of the indicative verb BE in the 1st and 3rd person singular of the past tense. The indicative form was is substituted in
less formal style :

If I were/was rich, I would buy you anything you wanted.
Tim always speaks quietly on the phone, as though he were/was telling a
secret.
I wish the journey were/was over.
Just suppose everyone were/was to give up smoking and drinking.
[…]



(CoGEL § 4.64) 'Mood markers': would and should
[…] we consider special uses of would and should in which these modals have nothing to do with the cognate modals will and shall, but are instead used to mark the MOOD of the clause.
(a) WOULD/SHOULD AS A MARKER OF HYPOTHETICAL MEANING
Would (and sometimes, with a 1st person subject, should) may express hypothetical meaning in main clauses:

If you pressed that button, the engine would stop.
If there were an accident, we would/should have to report it.

Would/should + infinitive contrasts in syntactic distribution, but not in
meaning, with the past tense and the were-subjunctive, both of which express
hypothetical meaning in many subordinate clauses. Hence the following
cannot be interpreted as unreal conditions (although they might, with some
difficulty, be interpreted in some other way; […]:

?If you pressed that button, the engine stopped. [3]
?If you would press that button, the engine would stop. [4]
In [3], the hypothetical past tense is wrongly used in the main clause, whereas in [4], the would construction is wrongly used in the subordinate clause.
[…]


?: native speakers are unsure about the grammaticality
CoGEL: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al
Additions prompted by comments from user TonyK
(I don't know why your last two examples are given a question mark. The first one is uncontroversial in the right context: "Things used to be much simpler when I was working here. If you pressed that button, the engine stopped." And the second one is, I think, perfectly grammatical in North American English.)
You assume that in example "3" "pressed" is a true past; this is not so because what is being discussed is hypothetical conditions; given this context, "pressed" has for reference the present or the future; with this in mind, the past in the matrix clause does not confer clearly the hypothetical meaning, which in this case is usually rendered only by "would + infinitive". The interrogation mark shows that native speakers might understand that a hypothetical condition is being formulated but the phrasing does not seem quite proper. In ex 4, the first verbal form is not usual in the context of hypothetical conditions. Here is below the table of the verb forms found in the context of hypothetical conditions, as given in CoGEL.




conditional clause
matrix clause




present and future reference
PAST
PAST MODAL



If I were younger
I would study classical Greek;



a. If I knew those facts
I would have less work to do.



b. If I watched TV tomorrow
it would not be for long.


past reference
PAST PERFECTIVE
PAST PERFECTIVE MODAL



If I had seen you
I would have invited you home.



c. If I had  known thoses facts
I would have had less work to do.



Fig 15.35 Verb forms with hypothetical conditions [ex. a, b, and c added by user LPH]

I don't know why your last two examples are given a question mark. The first one is uncontroversial in the right context: "Things used to be much simpler when I was working here. If you pressed that button, the engine stopped." And the second one is, I think,  perfectly grammatical in North American English.

@TonyK I wrote a reply to your comment in my answer.

I stand by my comment!

@TonyK: the second one is perfectly grammatical in certain dialects of North American English, and it's steadily gaining acceptance in the others. Fairly soon, all of us North Americans may be using it, but I don't think we're there yet.

The answer is relatively simple. The issue is not whether the proposition expressed in the sentence is (in fact) "unrealistic" but whether it is expressed as unrealistic or at least uncertain. You can use two ways of doing this.
One way of doing this involves the uses of the modal form, which can be used to express doubt.  The other, using the indicative, involves certainty on the part of the speaker by comparing the false statement with something so ridiculous that nobody including the listener could possibly imagine it was true..

If Tokyo is in Spain, then I'm a Dutchman.

The above is (or in my youth used to be) a common way of dismissing a suggestion as ridiculous.
The use of the modal form often expresses doubt rather than certainty.

Yes, the simple present can be used to express the speaker's view that a previous assertion is ridiculous. But it does so in tandem with a suitable pairing in the clauses:

Let me show you the no-wheels bicycle I invented.
-- If that contraption is a bicycle, then I'm a monkey.

The inference to be drawn from the remark is "I am not a monkey, and that's no bicycle".
Using an irrealis form would rob the construction of its meaning.

It is OK to use "is" instead of "were" when the condition is contrary to reality, but it means something different.

If Tokyo is in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia.

Normally you would say this if you did not know whether Tokyo was in Spain, but you did know that somehow the location of Tokyo determined the location of the Eiffel Tower in this way. But this sentence is being used as an example of the logical principle that you can derive any conclusion from a false premise. The overall sentence is true, precisely because Tokyo is not in Spain. But the other sentence is different.

If Tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower would be in Bolivia.

By using "were", you are acknowledging that you know Tokyo isn't really in Spain. You are talking about cause and effect, saying that Tokyo being in Spain would somehow cause the Eiffel Tower to be in Bolivia. (Or at least allow you to infer it.) Then the sentence becomes a false statement, but it's grammatical and meaningful.
It is very rare that we use "If X is Y then Z" when we know that Y is false, because, the way English works, that kind of sentence is only useful as an example of a principle of logic. If you want to say, "in the alternate universe where Y is true, unlike our universe where it's false, then Z has to be true", then you have to use "were".
